# OLAP Cube deployment issues in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, error-handling, deployment, olap, olap-cube

When I deploy the cube, it not working and exist 1 error and 6 warning like that. How can I fix it?

```
Error: The project could not be deployed to the '...' server because of the following connectivity problems
```

[image]

I tried change the server name but it not work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.